# SwiftUI inject environment variable on dismiss()?

Tags: swiftui

I have a view in SwiftUI that **requires an environment object to be injected** ex: `MyView().environmentObject(myObj)` but I cannot figure out how to inject it when navigating back to it from a dismissed view using either `@Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss` or `@Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode`.

Comment: Injection goes from parent to child not from child to parent. Since you are dismissing it should already be in the parent.

Comment: @loremipsum Thanks, dang, I seem to lose it on dismiss() somehow, which is strange because it was in that view and is passed into the child view fine.

Comment: impossible to help more specifically but make sure that the very first instance of `myObj` is a `StateObject` not a `ObservedObject` or even worse, neither of those.

Comment: @loremipsum Thanks!! I was initializing it by doing .environmentObject(myObj()) in my first view, so I just added a `@StateObject private var myObj: MyObj = MyObj()` and passed it instead like you suggested!! :)

Comment: Glad to help. I added an answer to you mind accepting with the green checkmark and maybe upvoting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Injection goes from parent to child not from child to parent. Since you are dismissing it should already be in the parent.

Make sure that the very first instance of `myObj` is a `StateObject` not a `ObservedObject` or even worse, neither of those.